# Load the last post of a category

Tags: categories, get-posts

I would like to load the last post when I go to the selected category.

For example
if I go to `http://site.com/category`
it loads `http://site.com/category/35/this-is-the-last-post`

Does exist some example to follow about that?
I'm doing practice with Wordpress and I don't know how can I get the `last post` of a category.

Answer (score 1):

Hook `template_redirect` and check if it's a category archive page, if so get the category ID from `query_vars` and `query_posts` for a single post from that category, which by default should be the most recent, then `wp_redirect` to the post's permalink.

This code would go in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_category_redirect() {
    if ( is_category() ) :
        query_posts('cat='. get_query_var('cat') .'&posts_per_page=1');
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() , 301 ); 
        exit; 
    endif;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_category_redirect' );
```